# I need this json data in the below format using JSONATA

Tags: json, jsonata

Below json is my input.

```
{
    "payload": {
        "KA01B3432": "KA01B3432",
        "KA02A3123": "KA02A3123"
    }
}
```

Using **JSONATA** i need to format the above JSON to below format.

```
[
    {
        "KA01B3432": "KA01B3432"
    },
    {
        "KA02A3123": "KA02A3123"
    }
]
```

I tried `payload.[$keys()]` but this will yield only keys in array format not whole object in array format.

```
{
    "payload": {
        "KA01B3432": "KA01B3432",
        "KA02A3123": "KA02A3123"
    }
}
```

to

```
[
    {
        "KA01B3432": "KA01B3432"
    },
    {
        "KA02A3123": "KA02A3123"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$spread(payload)` does what you need.

See http://try.jsonata.org/S1COdDqO4

Answer (score 0):

What about the following code :

```
   var json = { "payload": { "KA01B3432": "KA01B34321", "KA02A3123": "KA02A31231" } };
    var array = [];
    keys = Object.keys(json.payload);
    values = Object.values(json.payload);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var item = {};
        item[keys[i]] =  values[i];

        array.push(item);
    }
    console.log(array);
```

Comment: I used the same code but still it is not providing the expected result.

Comment: [ { key: 'KA01B3432', value: 'KA01B34321' },
  { key: 'KA02A3123', value: 'KA02A31231' } ]  This is what I recieved by running your code, but in the expected result there is no "Key" and "Value" words.

Comment: use this please  
 item[keys[i]] =  values[i];
i'm going to update the answer and this will provide exactly what you need